# Props are empty on passing them to child class based components while filled when using functional component

Tags: reactjs, react-props, react-component

It seems that props are not being passed to child component when my child component is a class based component. This is my parent component:

```
class ScreeningsList extends React.Component{
    state = {screenings: [] };

    componentDidMount = async () => {
        const response = await apis.getAllScreenings();
        this.setState({screenings: response.data});
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                <ScrTest screeningsList = {this.state.screenings}/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

And here is my child component:

```
class ScrTest extends React.Component{

    render(){
        return (
            <div className="screeningsContainer">
                <h2>Title: {this.props.screeningsList._id}</h2>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Here I tried just to display id of the screening. The value in props did not exist. There were no props at all. 
However when I use functional component and use the arrow function:

```
const ScreeningsToRender = props => {
...
}
```

I can access props by using props.screeningsList and use every value that is inside that prop. Rendering the component is succesfull and I can see the list of all the screenings. What should I do to recieve props properly in my child component?

Answer (score 0):

You need a constructor in the child component:

```
class ScrTest extends React.Component{

    constructor(props){
       super(props);
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <div className="screeningsContainer">
                <h2>Title: {this.props.screeningsList._id}</h2>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

"When implementing the constructor for a React.Component subclass, you should call super(props) before any other statement. Otherwise, this.props will be undefined in the constructor".
**Source**: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#constructor